# I'm handling an imbalanced dataset. Does applying SMOTE algorithm to up-sample the minority class yields same accuracy and roc_auc_score?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, imbalanced-data, smote

The following code shows how when trained on a SMOTE-produced dataset the accuracy and roc_auc_score comes out as same.

```
sm = SMOTE(random_state = 2) #creating SMOTE object
X_t, y_t = sm.fit_sample(X, y) #fitting X and y in smote and storing the new dataset in X_t and y_t
clf_temp = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf_temp.fit(X_t,y_t)
y_score = clf_temp.predict(X_t)
print(accuracy_score(y_t,y_score))
print(roc_auc_score(y_t,y_score))
```

`0.8015075376884422` 
`0.8015075376884422`

whereas on training the dataset on the same classifier without SMOTE gives a different result

```
clf_temp.fit(X,y)
y_score = clf_temp.predict(X)
print(accuracy_score(y,y_score))
print(roc_auc_score(y,y_score))
```

`0.7996592361209712` 
`0.7183922969169426`

Comment: Question should be asked [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). It's strange to see accuracy == auc... you can look at generated X_t and Y_t to see if there is no strange pattern